# Where do PayPal questions belong?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Pretty sure that questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999751/user-sees-the-item-name-instead-of-item-description-when-redirected-to-paypal) do not fit on Stack Overflow, as it's not related to programming whatsoever.

Do we have proper site for this in the network? Or should we just close it as general Off Topic?

Comment: "_SiteName_ is not a support site for third party services, please refer to the service's documentation, and/or contact the service directly."

Comment: @YannisRizos there are thousands of questions tagged PayPal so I doubt all of them are off topic - just those that are not related to programming.

Comment: Yes, I was commenting on the question you linked to.

Comment: It could be a programming question if he's not setting all the information he could. It could also be a Webmasters question.

Comment: I've definitely struggled with many of the PayPal-related questions as to whether or not they are off-topic for SO. For those that have _any inkling_ of programming in the question body, I tend to let be, but for those that don't mention code directly, I tend to mark as off-topic (usually directed to Webmasters). +1 for raising the issue.

Comment: This one seems to be on-topic if you ask me. It is an implementation question using an API, doesn't matter which API. It is answerable.

Answer (score 4):

It's an API that a programmer is attempting to perform a specific function in.  If we limited API discussion to non-commercial APIs only, or non-online APIs, we'd have precious few questions left.